# ZF2: Extend a Form View Helper and make it available from view

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to render a Multicheck options like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="avoid_transport[voiture]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="avoid_transport[plane]" value="1">
...
```

but I achieve to render like:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="avoid_transport[]" value="voiture">
 <input type="checkbox" name="avoid_transport[]" value="plane">
```

Following appreciate guide, I need to create a custom view extending the Multicheck View Helper, but I am having problems.

This is my extended class:

```
namespace Multicity\Helper;

use Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox as MultiCheckboxElement;


class FormMultiCheckboxArray extends MultiCheckboxElement
{
    public function render()
{
         /* do my own render here or render_options */
    return;
    }
}
```

I make it available through the view helper manager:

```
// module.config.php
'view_helper' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'formMultiCheckboxArray' => 'Multicity\Helper\FormMultiCheckboxArray'
     )
),
```

I create the form element using the extended class:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Multicity\Helper\FormMultiCheckboxArray',
    'name' => 'avoid_transport',
    'options' => array(
    'value_options' => array(
                           '0' => 'voiture',
                           '1' => 'avion',
                       ),
 ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => 1,
     )
));
```

and at the view:

```
<?php echo $this->formMultiCheckboxArray($form->get('avoid_transport')); ?>
```

And I get this error message:

```
Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for formMultiCheckboxArray
```

Please, anybody could help me to figure out what I am missing?

I will appreciate any kind of guide. Thank for your time.

Regards.

Comment: You're currently extending a form element, not a view helper. The multicheckbox view helper is located at `\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox`

Comment: Thanks for the notice, but the big mistake it is at the 'view_helper' key name, since it is 'view_helpers'. Fixing this, things seems to start working...